# Running a .exe file inside java code

Tags: java, windows, cmd, exe

I am trying to run a .exe file that I have generated inside a Java code. I have a GUI written in Java and the .exe file is generated using MATLAB (its actually a Simulink model). When I run the .exe file separately (i.e. I double click on it) it will create an output file ( which is what I expect) but when I run my Java code it opens the command prompt but it won't generate any outputs at all -in fact I am not even sure if it runs my .exe file or not.

Here is my code:

```
package combustionModel;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUIInterface extends JFrame {  
    JButton b1 = new JButton();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUIInterface gui = new GUIInterface();  
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(100, 200);
            final JFileChooser fc  = new JFileChooser();
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+file.getAbsolutePath());
                p.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public GUIInterface(){
        setVisible (true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,200);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel adpanel = new JPanel();
        JButton OK = new JButton();
        b1.addActionListener(new Action());
        adpanel.add(OK);
        adpanel.add(b1);
        super.add(adpanel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)!

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. @fge +1

Comment: You need to consume the process inputstream, as described in the javadoc, if possible not on the UI thread.

Comment: Remember that if you do this you will no longer have java's main advantage of compatibility.

Comment: But my code doesn't take any arguments as an input -it reads a couple of files but their directory is already hard coded in the .exe file- 
From what I see it actually runs my .exe -from seeing what it writes on the command prompt- but for some reason it doesn't generate the output files that it is supposed to generate! Thanks for your help! @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 1):

Try by passing the absolute path

example

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\program files\\test\\test.exe", null, new File("c:\\program files\\test\\"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+file.getAbsolutePath());
```

try this instead

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Tried this, still don't get any output files!