# Monitor heap usage of JVM in real time

Tags: java, memory, monitoring, heap-memory

I'm having real trouble understanding how to monitoring of JVMs heap usage is supposed to work. I've read multiple threads and they all use the same pattern, taken from this source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html

However, the listener never seams to fire an event. I just want to be able to display the current heap size of JVM in real time INSIDE my GUI. How can I do that?

Comment: From within the JVM process that's running, or from an external program? Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

Jvisualvm tool is what you need, it's in the bin repository of your jdk, search for jvisualvm.exe and launch it, you can check your heap and permgen memories in realtime.

Comment: Well I'd like to display it inside my GUI in a JTextArea :/

Comment: @Zorobay Then you're looking for `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`

Comment: If you want to display it inside a GUI I think this post can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364820/running-a-exe-file-inside-java-code this way you can invoke jvisualvm from your GUI

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JMX for this use case.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

... and similar methods in `Runtime` , give you instantaneous memory info. Set a scheduler to do this and update your GUI.

Of course, JMX is valuable if you want to monitor this kind of thing externally.

Comment: I might use this, thanks. Still, it is not as optimized as just listening for a change...:(

Comment: and if you wanna generate a graph out of this. Poll this in a loop and u will have required info to generate graph